# Submit Jobs to different Hadoop cluster from a single Oozie client

Tags: kerberos, oozie

I have a requirement where I need to submit a Job to different Hadoop cluster from a remote machine.

Both Hadoop clusters are Kerberos enabled.

What authentication/settings are required for it?

*P.S: I have setup oozie client on the remote node.*

Comment: _"Both Hadoop clusters are Kerberos enabled"_ > do they use the same KDC? Different KDC with trust? Completely different KDCs? If the latter, you are screwed.

Comment: The Oozie client does not matter _(just a thin REST API client with SPNego for Kerberos auth over HTTP)_ , it's the way the Oozie server connects to clusters A and B -- but with a single Kerberos identity -- that matters.

Comment: KDC is same for both cluster.

Comment: So, if `oozie` is defined as a Proxy account on both clusters, and if your own account is accepted in both clusters, then it's just a matter of setting the appropriate `nameNode` and `jobTracker` parameters in your workflow, and Oozie should contact the appropriate cluster to run your Actions. That's how Yahoo! operates its clusters from a single Oozie instance...